# How many coils of a wire in an electromagnet would make 100 milliTeslas field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, estimation

This is a rather stupid question. I'm making a basic electromagnet using copper wire and an iron nail and need to make an electromagnetic feild roughly about 100 milliTeslas . Ill be using a gauge 6 nail (4 inches long and 20d) and plastic insulated copper wire. Electricity generated by a microbial fuel cell would pass through with an output of about 250 volts. How can I find out the number of times I can coil the wire to get an electromagnetic feild close to that?
Any answer will be really appreciated.

Comment: I think it would be more to the spirit of physics.SE to ask for the concepts needed to calculate this (that is the formula) and then solve the problem yourself. Also note, that 240V is a measure of voltage, not of current. Furthermore, the material of the nail is crucial. I would recommend a high current transformator to operate the electromagnet at a lower voltage. The 240V suggest mains voltage in Europe, note that mains voltage is AC, therefore you will not get a constant magnetic field with mains voltage (but one oscillating at 50 Hz).

Comment: I will mark this up as an attempt to inform us that you are planning on entering the Darwin Awards. DO NOT, I repeat, DO NOT try to make an electromagnet with 240V line voltage. That is all I have to say about this, your parents can take care of the rest of the story if you don't listen.

Comment: I am so sorry, its 240 millivolts (edited). @CuriousOne , good joke, though.

Comment: @SebastianRiese , I would love to know the formula to calculate that. The nail would be made of iron. Ive tried researching, but due to my lack of knowledge in more advanced stuff, I dont really understand or know how to use what I find.

Comment: This is no joke whatsoever. You wouldn't be the first one to attempt something this foolish. 240mV of "current", on the other hand, is a joke. Good luck with that. I would suggest you try something that you have a borderline understanding of.

Comment: @CuriousOne Sorry about that, ive fixed that,too. Its not that dont understand what Im doing but that I dont know a lot about the theory behind this. And the one thing stopping me from making it is the lack of knowledge in coming up with a rough idea of how I can make an electromagnetic feild close to what i would like to make. Thanks for pointing that out, anyways.

Comment: Seriously, giving your difficulty of just getting the units right I would suggest you don't go anywhere near electricity unless it's professionally installed circuits. The theory needed to build a magnet with specified performance is far beyond your current level of expertise. If you need a magnet, just buy one. If you need an electromagnet, just buy one.

Comment: @Fluxenein "The nail would be made of iron." Iron is a damn complicated material. What *kind* of iron (that is: steel in what phase, pure iron (very unlikely for a nail), stainless steel (many varieties of which are not ferromagnetic)). $\mu_r$ ranges, for materials one would colloquially refer to as iron, from 1.003 for some stainless steels to 200000 for annealed pure iron, with values on the order 200 being common for carbon steel! See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_Permeability#Values_for_some_common_materials

Comment: Also - 0.1 T is pretty strong as magnetic fields go. That is 10,000 Gauss. In hospitals with MRI scanners, they draw a line on the floor at 5 Gauss - warning people that inside that line you have to be careful. Just don't have any credit cards nearby when you switch this thing on. Or cell phones. Or hammers. Metal will fly - and it _will_ hurt you.

Comment: @CuriousOne ,Sorry about that, Im still in secondary school and havent learned any of that. I dont think Ill be able to use it anyways, as I misunnderstood 100mT as a weak electromagnetic feild and Floris's comment corrected that misunderstanding. And thats why I didnt exactly get why you said that it would be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

I'll second CuriousOne's warnings about the dangers of electricity.  But if your fuel cell really will give you around 0.25V, and if you can afford to burn out components, I don't see how you could do much harm.  The internal resistance of microbial fuel cells appears to be pretty high (~35$\Omega$), so you'll only get around 7mA.

The concept you're looking for is the [solenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid#Quantitative_description).  The Wikipedia page has the formulas you need.  [This page](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/solids/ferro.html#c5) suggests that the relative permeability of iron is $\sim 200$.  If you want 100mT, you need a number of turns per unit length somewhere around
\begin{equation}
  \frac{N}{\ell} = \frac{B} {\mu_0\, \mu_r\, I} \approx \frac{0.1\mathrm{T}} 
  {(10^{-6} \mathrm{T\cdot m/A})\, (200)\, (0.007\mathrm{A})} \approx 70\,000
  \frac{1}{\mathrm{m}} = 70\frac{1}{\mathrm{mm}}.
\end{equation}
That is, you'd need 70 turns per millimeter.  A millimeter is pretty small, so that's sounding pretty difficult.  You have control over some things, though, so you might be able to improve it:

1. Use wire with the thinnest possible insulation.  Obviously, you need insulation so it doesn't short out.  In fact, you might try to get [magnet wire](http://www.coilgun.info/theory/magnetwire.htm).  But note Sebastian's comment below.  You need to beware of increasing the resistance of the wire.  I don't know what current-supply properties a fuel cell has.
2. Increase the $\mu_r$ of your [core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_core).  This means choosing a different material -- presumably one specifically designed for electromagnet cores.
3. Increase the current.  If you have more than one fuel cell, you could attach them in parallel to decrease their collective internal resistance.

And even then, remember that this field is concentrated inside the solenoid.  The iron nail will help a little, but the field you get outside of it won't be quite the same.  You might want to shape your core into a "C" shape.

Comment: Well I guess for 70 turns per millimeter the resistance of the copper wire cannot be neglected (especially since the solenoid has to be *long* for the used formula to apply). I guess it might just be impossible to reach 0.1T with a 0.25V source that has so high an internal resistance.

Comment: As @SebastianRiese says, resistance of the wire and the fuel cell both matter - and both can be improved by having more in parallel. You would end up with a pretty thick solenoid and an awful lot of fuel cells to get anywhere near - and when you do, it would be a dangerous thing.

Comment: @Mike , thanks for the help, I misunderstood 100mT as a weak electromagnetic feild. Im still in secondary school and havent learned anything close to Teslas. When Im coiling the wire,would it be possible to coil one wire over the other to get the 70 coils every mm?

Comment: In principle, yes, you can make the solenoid "walls" as thick as you want.  Those formulas you see on the wikipedia page, for example, are for the magnetic field anywhere inside, and they don't say anything about the inner or outer radius of the wires.  So you can wind over and over to increase the field strength.  But the simpler formulas I used do assume an infinite length solenoid, so if the outer radius of your wires is comparable to the length of your solenoid, those formulas might not be so accurate.